# ZF2 - how to create a Dynamic Form Creation?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I need to create a simple settings module for all the configuration settings of my modules. This is the database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `base_settings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `module` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parameter` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `base_settings`
--

INSERT INTO `base_settings` (`id`, `type`, `module`, `label`, `parameter`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 'select', 'cms', 'Layout', 'defaultlayout', '2column-left'),
(2, 'text', 'cms', 'Items', 'itemsnum', '5');
```

Now what I need to do is creating a form with two or more fields using the records in the base_settings table.

[image]

For instance the first record handle the preferences of the **defaultlayout** and its value is **2column-layout**. So I need to create a form with one or more form fields for each record saved in that table.

```
namespace Base\Entity;

class Settings implements SettingsInterface {

    public $id;
    public $module;
    public $parameter;
    public $value;


    /**
     * This method get the array posted and assign the values to the table
     * object
     *
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function exchangeArray ($data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
            $this->$field = (isset($value)) ? $value : null;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $id
     */
    public function getId ()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $id
     */
    public function setId ($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $module
     */
    public function getModule ()
    {
        return $this->module;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $module
     */
    public function setModule ($module)
    {
        $this->module = $module;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $parameter
     */
    public function getParameter ()
    {
        return $this->parameter;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $parameter
     */
    public function setParameter ($parameter)
    {
        $this->parameter = $parameter;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $value
     */
    public function getValue ()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $value
     */
    public function setValue ($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}
```

This is the result that I want to achieve **dynamically**:

```
<?php
namespace CmsSettings\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;

class PageForm extends Form
{

    public function init ()
    {
        $hydrator = new ClassMethods;

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setHydrator($hydrator)->setObject(new \Base\Entity\Settings()); // I have a doubt about this hydrator

        $this->add(array (
                'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
                'name' => 'defaultlayout',
                'attributes' => array (
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                ),
                'options' => array (
                        'label' => _('Layout'),
                        'value_options' => array (
                                '1column' => _('1 Column'),
                                '2column-left' => _('2 Columns Left'),
                                '2column-right' => _('2 Columns Right'),
                        )
                )
        ));


        $this->add(array (
                'name' => 'itemsnum',
                'attributes' => array (
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                ),
                'options' => array (
                        'label' => _('Items'),
                )
        ));

        $this->add(array ( 
                'name' => 'submit', 
                'attributes' => array ( 
                        'type' => 'submit', 
                        'class' => 'btn btn-success', 
                        'value' => _('Save')
                )
        ));
        $this->add(array (
                'name' => 'id',
                'attributes' => array (
                        'type' => 'hidden'
                )
        ));
    }
}
```

the question is: how to create this dynamic form ? Where have I to start?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you wanna be doing is:

- You write yourself a class like `DbFormCreator`
- You query the DB for all possible settings
- You inject those settings into the Form
- For each setting you simply create the FormField of the appropriate type and name

Things start to get more tricky once you have `value_options` like in your layout example. In this case your `DbFormCreator` needs to pull the data for `value_options` from either another table or some configuration files.

This kind of task can become extremely complex as ultimately you'll not only need to add information for `type` and `name` into your database, but also information for `filters`, `validators`, etc... You can take a look at what `Apigility` does inside their API form for adding new fields to the API. Basically the same backend from that should be applicable to your scenario.

This isn't the most easiest of task (not the most complex either), but certainly not something you'll get an answer for. The basics are explained above, but the work is up to you.